# Set up a test Url configuration on local machine

Tags: django, apache, url, localhost

In my Django Project, I need to add social authentication. 
I am following [this](https://github.com/yudazilian/SocialAuthDjangoTutorial) tutorial.

One of the steps is to [Set up a test Url configuration on local machine](https://github.com/yudazilian/SocialAuthDjangoTutorial#b-set-up-a-test-url-configuration-on-our-local-machine). Which is, say my test url is: myname.example.com. Then, myname.example.com should load at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (on the Django Localhost Server)

I added `127.0.0.1 myname.example.com`to `/etc/hosts` but that doesnt work.

How should this be done in Ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 1):

The `hosts` file only takes care about hostname resolution. It does not do anything with the ports in use. So your site will be available on http://myname.example.com:8000

Possible ways to have your site running under http://myname.example.com

#### runserver

In order to use "privileged" ports your process needs to run as *root* user. When using virtualenv you also have to specify tha path to the respective python binary:

```
sudo /your/virtualenv/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

#### nginx

Install nginx (or apache) and setup a minimal reverse proxy:

```
# nginx config
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name myname.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

#### ssh

Use port forwarding locally via ssh. Here again you need root privileges to bind ports below 1024. The following command forwards connections to port 80 on `127.0.0.1` to port 8000 on `127.0.0.1`

```
sudo ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:8000 <your_user>@127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I tried all 3 methods but it didnt work. 

1. `sudo ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` throws ImportError: No module named social.apps.django_app. Thats strange since I have `pip install python-social-auth2`.

2. I added the nginx code to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and restarted the nginx. `https://myname.example.com/` gives 404.

3. `sudo ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:8000 shubham@127.0.0.1` gives `ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused`. 

I am running all these codes in a virtualenv. What else can I try?

Comment: see updated answer. you have to specify the python binary. or - use `su` to become root first and then activate the virtualenv as root.

Comment: `>> sudo /home/shubham/.virtualenvs/eComm/bin/python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`

<<_You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP_

Set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False` in `settings.py` but no change.

Comment: You did not mention that you need HTTPS - the runserver does not support HTTPS. And it also would not be port 80 but 443 for SSL.  For a `runserver` replacement with SSL support you could use [django-sslserver](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver).

Comment: I dont need HTTPS, Its default in Django. 
You've been great help! Thanks! 
I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: ok :) - HTTPS is not default in Django. Eventually it is default for the callbacks for some of the social-auth providers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Django projects, but as regards setting up a test URL connection to your local-host IP with your chosen domain name, you can do that by using the BIND software, configure your zones and your domain name as the myname.example.com, or if you already have one, create your local zone file to include your local Ip machine number so that way you can "nslookup 127.0.0.1" and your domain name which should resolve to the same name if you look up the IP and vice versa(that is nslookup myname.example.com should resolve to 127.0.0.1), the easier way to do it would be to open your host hile (etc/host/ add myname.example.com beside your 127 Ip address) then go the resolve.conf file and also put in the same parameters. The second stage would be to use apache as your web directory and configure your sites enabled with the same information. then on your chosen port 8000, put the information for the URL link in your Var/www directory and bind it to port 8000. That way when you open your browser with 127 Ip or myname.example.com, you should see the message it works! letting you know your domain is available, once you append the 8000 to the URL link you should see the information you copied and bound to your domain at the specified port. This is off the top of my head, so you would need reference materials if you choose to follow the specs to meet your system distro and configs. But that's pretty much the basic Idea of setting up a URL link.

Comment: Please put a few references, its difficult to follow otherwise.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: this is for apache  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: And if you want specific port 8000 you would have to set your web browser settings to listen on both 80 and 8000, or however you choose... this would help you complete the task http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html

Comment: I'm trying the steps in the above answer first. Its more organized and understandable. If that doesnt work, I'll try with your method. Thanks though :)